# How to access data from google BigQuery tables present in different projects in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I want to select data from two google BigQuery tables from two different projects and do union all operations on that in spark. I am getting error **Errorcom.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden**.

I think that the BigQuery properties like buketId,ProjectId.. are set in configuration level. So when accessing data from multiple projects it's throwing error.

Please suggest if there any way to access data from multiple BigQuery tables from different projects.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spark + BigQuery, but how are you authenticating? Using a service account?

Comment: Yes using service account.

Comment: I'm also not familiar with spark, but to make sure, you shared your dataset correctly? See:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#primitive_roles_for_projects